# MyBatis select by id always returns zero

Tags: java, mysql, orm, mybatis

With the following configuration:

POJO:

```
public class Student {
    private int studentId;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    // getters and setters
}
```

StudentMapper.xml

```
...
<select id="findStudentById" parameterType="int" resultType="Student">
  SELECT student_id, name, email FROM Student WHERE studentId = #{studentId}
</select>
...
```

StudentMapper interface

```
public interface StudentMapper {
    ...
    Student findStudentById(int studentId);
    ...
}
```

The problem is whenever I run `StudentService.findStudentById(studentId)` (*I did not put it here*) I got the **same number (zero)** every time (student_id in my table is auto_generated and started from 1 not 0)

**EDIT**: but other params (name and email) is returned properly

Answer (score 1):

MyBatis can't map `student_id => studentId` by default. You have multiple options here: configure MyBatis to transform underscore to camelCase or use a `resultMap`.

[Config](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#settings) example:

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
    </settings>
</configuration>
```

[Result map](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps) example:

```
<resultMap id="studentMap">
    <result property="studentId" column="student_id"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <result property="email" column="email"/>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: this setting is giving SAXParserException

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us the code that insert data in the database, so I'm going to guess what you are probably doing wrong. Although you are using an auto_generated column in your table, when you are inserting the Student data you are sending the int studentId to it. I also imagine that you are not defining any value for it, since you are expecting it to be auto generated, so MyBatis will add the default value of a int to student_id, which is 0.